# sql alchemy : derived column example

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
#necessary import goes here
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1/test',echo=False)
print 'Engine created'
connection=engine.connect()
metadata=MetaData(engine)
metadata.bind=engine
Session =  sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
mapping = Table('mapping',metadata,autoload=True)

class Mapping(object):
    pass
MappingMapper=mapper(Mapping,mapping)
```

Now i am able to write basic query for insert,update,delete,filter etc.

Q:1   I need to write complex query, where i do derive new columns based on existing columns. Ex.  ColA,ColB is there on table, ColC is not part of table structure. 
Select (ColA+ColB) as ColC from table where ColC > 50 order by  ColC.

I am clueless how to convert above like query with SqlAlchemy.  How to map, how to retrieve.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to use[Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html). 
In your case, just change the declaration of the class to the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Mapping(object):
    @hybrid_property
    def ColC(self):
        return self.ColA + self.ColB
```

Then the query:

```
qry = session.query(Mapping).filter(Mapping.ColC > 80)
```

will generate SQL:

```
SELECT mapping.id AS mapping_id, ...
FROM mapping
WHERE mapping."ColA" + mapping."ColB" > ?
```

Comment: thanks, what if i dont want to hard code table's column details in python code but want to use Metadata('mapping',metatdata,autoload=True)  m not sure how to do it, my table has 40 column and i dont want to write it down all in python.

Comment: Thanks! it was easy, but i was not able to figure it out how, now it is done. Thanks @van